# Macro to split text string into their own columns - no fixed length/delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

I need help figuring out an easy way (preferably a macro) to split data entered in 1 cell (separated by spaces - lengths are not fixed) into their own columns. I have about 100k entries to work with.

I am currently doing this using a combination of Left, Right, Find functions but it's taking me forever.

Sample data layout (All in Column A): http://prntscr.com/32l81u

I'm looking for a way to split each line into columns based on their entries. The only piece of information with fixed length is the first entry for each set which is 9 characters long. I need all the entries in each set to be their own columns. Each set is separated by the series of --- and |

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `TextToColumns`? If so, why is it not applicable in your data? Also can you add a screen shot of your expected results.

Comment: I agree with @L42: Why a macro when Excel already provides you a means to achieve what you want. `Text To Columns` If you still want VBA code then record a macro for text to columns. It is still faster than looping through all the cells in the column ;)

Comment: I tried Text To Columns but since there are no fixed lengths and common delimiters (aside from the space) I still end up manually fixing the data.

Comment: It also splits some of the texts that shouldn't be. Ex: LastName, First Name Middle Initial. If I use space (treat consecutive delimiters as oen) it splits the complete name up to separate columns. Same for phone numbers etc.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of expected results http://prntscr.com/37hgdk Highlighted in yellow are the ones that are important to stay in the same cell/column. Thanks!

Comment: @user3468115 It's probably possible, but I am not going to manually input data from your screenshot.  Furthermore, your screenshot is inconsistent with your description where you imply that all the data to be split is in one cell; your screen shot implies multiple cells to be converted to a single row.  Please download a file that we can use for testing.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry if my description's unclear. Here's a sample file with the desired outcome in a separate tab - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnkulniw9h25bsg/Sample.xlsx

Comment: @user3468115 The posted file allows better analysis of the problem. Major issues include not only the lack of fixed spacing, and defined separators, but also the fact that not all fields are mandatory (the first entry is missing several fields).  Your next step is to go through the 25 fields, and determine whether they are optional or not; and also what the allowable contents might be.  For example, will field (column) 18 ALWAYS contain "PROMO:"; or might it contain something else; and might it be optional.  Will field 11 always be an entry surrounded by parentheses (...)?  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your example source data contains four different formats.  You may believe there are only four formats but my experience of such tasks is that you will find another format starting on row 312 then another on row 1543 and so on.

You have to code the first version of the macro for the data you expect to find but you must check the data conforms to your expectations.  If a set fails to conform to expectations, amend the macro to handle this new format as well as previous formats and try the macro again.  It may take many versions before the macro can successfully decode an entire source worksheet.

The code below contains comments to tell what it is doing but here I will explain my approach.

The code contains a great many statements of the form: `Debug.Assert boolean-expression`.  These statements check my assumptions and the code will stop if the expression returns False.  I have made no attempt to carry on if an assumption is false.  It would be possible to skip to the next set and carry on to find more faulty assumptions but I have always found it easiest to fix one problem at a time.

I process the contents of the sets as a list of tokens which I expect to appears in a a small number of fixed sequences.  I define a token as something separated from its neighbour by two or more spaces.  I have a routine `GetTokenArray` which moves the complexity of splitting the cell values into its own routine.  If my definition of a token is faulty then this is the routine that will need to be rewritten.

Please note: a token does not necessary match a column.  If my understanding of the source data is correct, the first token of a set will be something like: "aaaaaaaaa Doe, John".  This will have to be divided into two.

In examples 1 and 2, the second line starts `MM/DD/YY   City, St ZCode` while in examples 3 and 4 it starts `MM/DD/YY   LName, FNam MName`.  It would take some clever code to reliably distinguish addresses from names if you have to allow for non-American addresses.  Example 3 and 4 have `MM/DD/YY   City, St ZCode` as the start of line 4.  Unless there is some fixed difference between these two formats that a macro can identify, you have a serious problem.

One of my reasons for getting an entire set as an array is that it allows the macro to look ahead easily if this would help to identify the format of the set.

I hope the code below gets you started.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CtrlDecode()

  Dim InxTA As Long
  Dim RowOutCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim TokenPart() As String
  Dim SrcData As Variant
  Dim TokenArray() As String

  ' It might be possible to place output column values directly into a cell
  ' or into an array for writing to an output row.  However, it seems to me
  ' that it will be easier to place column values into specific variables
  ' as the set is processed and then move them when processing has finished.
  ' No doubt you will want to replace my variable names with something more
  ' appropriate.
  Dim Id1 As String      ' Leading nine character identifier
  Dim Name As String
  Dim Id2 As String      ' XX/XXX/XXXXX
  Dim Id3 As String      ' XXX/xx

  ' This macro outputs decoded data to worksheet "Output".
  ' Change as necessary.
  With Worksheets("Output")
    ' Delete all data created by previous run of macro.
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    ' Set column widths
    .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 11#
    .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 25#
    .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 12#
    .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 7.14
  End With

  ' This macro reads source data from worksheet "Source".
  ' Change as necessary.

  With Worksheets("Source")
    ' Find last row containing data
    RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Load all data into an array.  I believe this will be more convenient
    ' that accessing the data cell by cell and it will be faster.
    SrcData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowSrcLast, 1)).Value
  End With

  RowSrcCrnt = 1
  RowOutCrnt = 1

  Do While RowSrcCrnt <= RowSrcLast
    ' Record start row of current set for error message
    Call GetTokenArray(SrcData, RowSrcCrnt, TokenArray)

    ' First token.
    ' Expect 9-character-id space FName comma space LName
    TokenPart = Split(TokenArray(1), " ")
    ' Expect three parts: first with length of 9, second ending
    ' in comma.
    Debug.Assert UBound(TokenPart) = 2
    Debug.Assert Len(TokenPart(0)) = 9
    Debug.Assert Right(TokenPart(1), 1) = ","
    Id1 = TokenPart(0)
    Name = TokenPart(1) & " " & TokenPart(2)

    ' Second token.
    ' Expect xx/xxx/xxxxx
    TokenPart = Split(TokenArray(2), "/")
    Debug.Assert UBound(TokenPart) = 2
    Debug.Assert Len(TokenPart(0)) = 2
    Debug.Assert Len(TokenPart(1)) = 3
    Debug.Assert Len(TokenPart(2)) = 5
    Id2 = TokenArray(2)

    ' Third token.
    ' Expect xxx/xx
    TokenPart = Split(TokenArray(3), "/")
    Debug.Assert UBound(TokenPart) = 1
    Debug.Assert Len(TokenPart(0)) = 3
    Debug.Assert Len(TokenPart(1)) = 2
    Id3 = TokenArray(3)

    ' Continue with remaining tokens.  The next few tokens appears to be
    ' the same in all formats so you could continue accessing TokenArray(4),
    ' TokenArray(5) and so on as I have.  It then looks as though the tokens
    ' present vary from format to format.  You will then have to use a
    ' variable, such as InxTA, and have code like:
    '   If TokenArray(InxTA) is optional token xyz Then
    '     VariableXyz = TokenArray(InxTA)
    '     InxTA = InxTA + 1
    '   Else
    '     VariableXyz = ""
    '   End If

    ' There are a variety of ways of transferring values to the output
    ' worksheet.  I suspect a cell by cell write is the easiest although
    ' not the fastest.
    With Worksheets("Output")
      .Cells(RowOutCrnt, "A").Value = Id1
      .Cells(RowOutCrnt, "B").Value = Name
      .Cells(RowOutCrnt, "C").Value = Id2
      .Cells(RowOutCrnt, "D").Value = Id3
      RowOutCrnt = RowOutCrnt + 1
    End With

  Loop

End Sub
Sub GetTokenArray(SrcData As Variant, RowSrcCrnt As Long, TokenArray() As String)

  ' * SrcData(1 To X, 1 To 1) contains all the data from the source worksheet
  ' * On entry, RowSrcrnt points at the first row of a set.  On exit, it points
  '   at the first row of the next set.
  ' * On exit, TokenArray will dimensioned as (1 To N) where N is the number of
  '   tokens found.  Each entry will contain one token in the sequence found.
  ' * A set is ended by a row starting "-----" and containing nothing but
  '   hyphens and pipes.
  ' * A token is separated from its neighbour by two or more spaces.

  Debug.Assert RowSrcCrnt < UBound(SrcData, 1) ' SrcData already processed

  ' The upper bound of 500 is intended to be more than could possibly be
  ' required so as not to bother with enlarginging a small array when it
  ' becomes full.
  ReDim TokenArray(1 To 500)

  Dim DataCrnt As String
  Dim InxTA As Long
  Dim PosCrnt As Long
  Dim Pos2Spaces As Long

  InxTA = 0

  Do While True
    DataCrnt = SrcData(RowSrcCrnt, 1)
    Debug.Assert DataCrnt <> ""  ' Unexpected empty row
    ' Check for row being end of set
    If Left(DataCrnt, 5) = "-----" And _
       Replace(Replace(DataCrnt, "-", ""), "|", "") = "" Then
      ' End of set
      Exit Do
    End If

    ' Extract all token from current row
    PosCrnt = 1
    Do While True

      Do While True
        ' Search for non-space
        If PosCrnt > Len(DataCrnt) Then
          ' End of cell value
          Exit Do
        End If
        If Mid(DataCrnt, PosCrnt, 1) <> " " Then
          ' Start of next token found
          Exit Do
        End If
        PosCrnt = PosCrnt + 1
      Loop  ' until end of cell or next token

      If PosCrnt > Len(DataCrnt) Then
        ' This cell finished
        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1
        Debug.Assert RowSrcCrnt < UBound(SrcData)  ' Last set not terminated
        Exit Do
      Else
        ' Have found first character of next token
        Pos2Spaces = InStr(PosCrnt, DataCrnt, "  ")
        If Pos2Spaces = 0 Then
          ' Everything up to end of cell is last token of cell
          InxTA = InxTA + 1
          ' Trim to remove trailing single space
          TokenArray(InxTA) = Trim(Mid(DataCrnt, PosCrnt))
          ' This cell finished
          RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1
          Debug.Assert RowSrcCrnt <= UBound(SrcData)  ' Last set not terminated
          Exit Do
        Else
          ' Everything up to 2 spaces is next token of this cell
          InxTA = InxTA + 1
          TokenArray(InxTA) = Mid(DataCrnt, PosCrnt, Pos2Spaces - PosCrnt)
          PosCrnt = Pos2Spaces + 2
        End If
      End If
    Loop  ' until end of cell
  Loop  ' until end of set

  Debug.Assert InxTA > 0  ' Empty set

  ' Discard unused entries
  ReDim Preserve TokenArray(1 To InxTA)
  RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1       ' Step over dividing row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @TonyDallimore I will give this a try. There's a lot of information that someone just starting to learn macros, like me, will find very helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: There are two aspects to my answer. The code shows how to solve this type of problem in VBA. I have not explained the VBA statements because once you know a statement exists, it is usually easy to look them it up.  The text explains the issues associated with this type of problem which apply to any programming language.  This is a problem I have encountered many times: the source data is not documented and is not entirely consistent so must be tidied up for convenient processing. Ask questions if necessary. Welcome to the joys of programming. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub parser()
    Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To N
        ary = Split(wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text), " ")
        k = 2
        For j = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            Cells(i, k).Value = ary(j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked but also need to find a way to keep some of the contents in 1 column. The most important ones are: the 9 digit ID, LName FName, Phone Numbers (they're in (000) 000-0000 format), Address 1 (Street # and Street Name) and Address 2 (City, State and Zip Code)

Comment: @user3468115  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's alright, thank you for the code you provided though. I'm still learning how to write macros and I'm sure this will come in handy. Thanks again!